# Datadog Python log collection from self-hosted Github Runner

Tags: python, docker, github-actions, datadog, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to collect logs from cron jobs running on our self hosted Github runners, but so far can only see the actual github-runner host logs.

I've created a self-hosted Github Runner in AWS running on Unbtu with a standard config.

We've also installed the Datadog agent v7 with their script and basic configuration, and added log collection from files using [these instructions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/?tab=tailfiles#custom-log-collection)

Our config for log collection is below.

```sh
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script.sh -o ddinstall.sh
export DD_API_KEY=${datadog_api_key}
export DD_SITE=${datadog_site}
export DD_AGENT_MAJOR_VERSION=7
bash ./ddinstall.sh

# Configure logging for GitHub runner
tee /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/runner-logs.yaml << EOF
logs:
  - type: file
    path: /home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_diag/Worker_*.log
    service: github
    source: github-worker
  - type: file
    path: /home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_diag/Runner_*.log
    service: github
    source: github-runner
EOF
chown dd-agent:dd-agent /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/runner-logs.yaml

# Enable log collection
echo 'logs_enabled: true' >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
systemctl restart datadog-agent
```

After these steps, I can see logs from our Github runners servers. However, on those runners we have several python cron jobs running in Docker containers, logging to stdout. I can see those logs in the Github Runner UI, but they're not available in Datadog, and those are the logs I'd really like to capture, so I can extract metrics from.

Do the docker containers for the python scripts need some special datadog setup as well? Do they need to log to a file that the datadog agents registers as a log file in the setup above?

Comment: It sounds like the data dog agent needs to be setup in each of the docker containers so that the stdout logs can be captures and sent. Otherwise the agent should only be picking up the host machines logs and never the docker container ones.

Comment: Ah, that oddly enough makes sense. I'll give that a go, Edward, and post back my findings! Thanks and happy holidays